# Changing the editor background colour in Eric IDE

Tags: python, eric

I'm using the Eric python IDE (version 6), but I can't find a way to change the background colour of the code editor. It has picked up the dark background colour of my Kubuntu theme, making code very hard to read (but other editors such as Kate and Idle don't do this).

I've tried Settings > Preferences > Editor > Style, enabled the 'Override edit area colours' option and then changed the colour in 'Edit area background' but this seems to have had no effect.

What is the correct way to do this? And what exactly does the 'Edit area background' setting do?

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and the output of 'apt policy eric' is:

```
eric:
  Installed: 17.11.1-1
  Candidate: 17.11.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 17.11.1-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

Settings > Preferences > Editor > Style, just changes the first unknown file type.

You need to change:

Settings > Preferences > Editor > Highlighters > Styles --- choose a language
Python 3 or 2

[eric6-preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zolH.png)